# Can you render a partial result in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering is there a way to render a partial view in the controller. So like you have a partial view and instead of returning it you render it right there in that controller method and store the result into a string or something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render a view as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the earlier stackflow thread at [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string/1241257#1241257)

Also, http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/render-partial-view-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc

I haven't tried it personally though... good luck.

Comment: It works with default view engine and others, but when you use other, it can be done easier.